# How prevent Angular@12 rendering a 'onload' property on the <link>-tag when using SCSS

Tags: angular, sass, angular12

When using SCSS in Angular@12 the -tag has a property `onload`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.672c1ac3d6da8cc311a2.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.672c1ac3d6da8cc311a2.css"></noscript>
```

However when the SCSS is empty or no SCSS is used it only renders:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c.css">
```

When using CSP-Headers that only allow 'self':

```
default-src https://*.mysite.nl ; child-src 'self' ; connect-src 'self' ; font-src 'self' ; frame-src 'self' ; frame-ancestors 'self' ; img-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' ; style-src 'self' ;
```

this results in a violation of the CSP-Header. Now I need to add `'unsafe-inline'` to the `script-src`. I do not want that!

Is it possible to force the production build not to use the `onload`?

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

Adding `"inlineCritical": false` to the `angular.json` solved my problem.

```
        "configurations": {
            "production": {

              "optimization": {
                "styles": {
                  "inlineCritical": false
                }
              }
            },
          },
```

Comment: This configuration is mentioned in [the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-optimization-options). Furthermore, [this blog](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2021/01/21/angular-cli-11.1/#critical-css-inlining) gives additional context.